# std::out_of_range When sorting through a vector

Tags: c++, function, sorting, vector

I am trying to take an input number, make a vector with that many elements, take in those elements, and then sort the elements by largest to smallest. I believe I am close but I am getting an error :

```
Exited with return code -6 (SIGABRT).
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 5) >= this->size() (which is 5)
```

Example: if the input is 5 10 4 39 12 2, the output should be 39,12,10,4,2,

Here is my code, I am thinking that I am getting the error from looping through my function, but I cannot figure out which one and I have tried changing all the loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void SortVector(vector<int>& myVec){
   int tempNum;
   for (int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i){
      if (myVec.at(i) < myVec.at(i+1)){
         tempNum = myVec.at(i);
         myVec.at(i) = myVec.at(i + 1);
         myVec.at(i + 1) = tempNum;
      }
   }
}

void print(vector<int>& myVec){
   for(int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i){
      cout << myVec.at(i)<<", ";
   }
}
      
int main() {
   int numOfVector;
   cin >> numOfVector;
   vector<int> myVec(numOfVector);
   
   for(int i = 0; i < numOfVector; ++i){
      cin >> myVec.at(i);
   }
   
   SortVector(myVec);
   print(myVec);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `i+1` when `i` reaches the maximum allowed by `i < myVec.size()`? Is it a valid `vector` index?

Comment: What happens when `myVec.size() == 5`, `i==4`, and `myVec.at(i+1)` is called?

Comment: What I generally do is start the loop at 1 and use `i-1`.

Comment: *but I cannot figure out which one* -- It is occurring at one of the calls to `at()`.  Slowly remove each call to `at()` by using `[]` instead, and do this until you see which `at()` call is causing the exception.

Comment: If you run it under a debugger it will fault at the bad line and you can examine the state of the program

Answer (score 3):

The loop of your sort runs through every element, and then examines the element that follows. When you are on the last index in the array, then there is no next element and so the `at` method throws `std::out_of_range`.

So you need to either loop up to `size - 1`, *or* start at index 1 and look at the *previous*. I prefer the latter because I don't like having `size - 1` evaluated on every loop.

Something like this:

```
void SortVector(vector<int>& myVec)
{
   for (size_t i = 1; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
   {
      if (myVec[i - 1] < myVec.[i]) {
         std::swap(myVec[i - 1], myVec[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Notice that I'm not using `at`. There is no point, because you have already range-checked the index by iterating over and indexing within a valid range.

I also used `std::swap` (from `<utility>`). Don't roll your own swaps. It's harder to read, and vulnerable to errors. Okay, maybe do it *once* in your life purely as an exercise and then use the proper method ever after.

It should be mentioned that your "sort" only does one pass of a bubble sort. You need an extra loop if you want to sort the entire vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing memory outside the vector when `i` is equal to `myVec.size() - 1` in the for loop because in this case the expression `myVec.at(i+1)` is equivalent to `myVec.at(myVec.size())`

```
void SortVector(vector<int>& myVec){
   int tempNum;
   for (int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i){
      if (myVec.at(i) < myVec.at(i+1)){
         tempNum = myVec.at(i);
         myVec.at(i) = myVec.at(i + 1);
         myVec.at(i + 1) = tempNum;
      }
   }

}
```

But in any case your function actually does not sort the vector because it is not enough to use only one for loop.

It seems you are trying to use the bubble sort method but it requires one more for loop.

And the code looked simpler if you used the standard function `std::swap` to swap adjacent elements of the vector. And there is no need to use the member function `at` instead of the subscript operator provided that the function is written correctly.

Instead of the manually written sorting function you could use the standard function `std::sort` as for example

```
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

void SortVector(vector<int>& myVec)
{
    std::sort( std::begin( myVec ), std::end( myVec ), std::greater<>() );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

void SortVector( std::vector<int> &myVec )
{
    std::sort( std::begin( myVec ), std::end( myVec ), std::greater<>() );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    std::vector<int> myVec = { 5, 10, 4, 39, 12, 2 };

    for ( const auto &item : myVec )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';        

    SortVector( myVec );

    for ( const auto &item : myVec )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';        
}
```

The program output is

```
5 10 4 39 12 2 
39 12 10 5 4 2
```